# Blazor WebAssembly call a JS function on error without using observer

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

With Blazor WebAssembly, when an error occurs, it shows the `div` with id "blazor-error-ui".

Is it possible to call a JS function when an error occur without using an observer and without using the framework ?

Comment: I removed my answer as it didn't do what I thought. In that case, I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've dug a little deeper and it seems that the Blazor WebAssembly framework calls `window.Module.printErr()` whenever a runtime error happens.

I'm not a JavaScript expert, but it seems like you could intercept that call.

A naive implementation that proves the method would be to replace your script to load blazor webassembly in the index.html with this:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
 <script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    Blazor.start().then(function () {

      window["OLDprintErr"] = window.Module.printErr

      window.Module.printErr = e => { 

        window["OLDprintErr"](e) // invoke standard behaviour

        alert(e) // invoke custom behaviour - just an alert for POC

      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

With that in place, any runtime errors will pop an alert and trigger the standard blazor-error-ui - of course you can replace the call to `alert` with whatever you want.

It is beyond my JS skills to do this in a nicer way, but I leave that to the reader / comments below - if any decent JS improvements appear I will edit the answer.